# C - Como passar um vetor no qual contém ponteiros para struct como parâmetro de uma função?

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Primeiramente criei um vetor de struct.
A seguir criei um vetor de ponteiros, no qual cada elemento desse vetor aponta para cada elemento do vetor de struct.

Por fim, preciso passar ambos (o vetor de structs e o vetor de ponteiros) como parâmetros de uma função. Já tentei de alguns modos pesquisando aqui no site, mas deu erro. Eu simplesmente não sei como fazer isso.

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct dados
{
   int dia, mes, ano;
   char nome_mes[50];
   char remetente[100];
   char destinatario[100];
};

void ordenar(struct dados *cartas, ***O QUE COLOCAR AQUI***, int n){
   //DUVIDA NESSA FUNÇÃO
}


void main(){

    int n, i;
    char lixo[5];
    scanf("%d\n", &n);

    struct dados cartas[n], *ponteiros[n];

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    ponteiros[i] = &cartas[i];
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d de ", &cartas[i].dia);
        scanf("%s", cartas[i].nome_mes);
        scanf("%s", lixo);
        scanf(" %d\n", &cartas[i].ano);
        gets(cartas[i].remetente);
        gets(cartas[i].destinatario);
    }

    //DÚVIDA AQUI !!!
    ordenar(cartas, ponteiros, n);

}
```

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Tem duas sintaxes possiveis para o fazer. A primeira é identica à que utilizou para o parametro `cartas` assim:

```
void ordenar(struct dados *cartas, struct dados **ponteiros, int n){
//                                               ^---
```

Como sendo um ponteiro de ponteiros.

Outra forma é utilizar a notação de array de ponteiros, quase igual à que utilizou quando declarou:

```
void ordenar(struct dados *cartas, struct dados *ponteiros[], int n){
//                                              ^---------^
```

Em ambas as formas é sempre necessário passar o tamanho para conseguir percorrer a quantidade de elementos que existem, e a utilização do parâmetro dentro da função a vai ser igual.

Como ultimo aparte, se o código não é para fins lúdicos e/ou educativos, lembre-se que já existe a função [`qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) para ordenar vetores, que lhe simplifica bastante  o trabalho.